# Why does TEdit.OnChange trigger when Ctrl+A is pressed?

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe7

I am running a Delphi XE7 VCL app on Windows 7.

I have observed that the `TEdit.OnChange` event triggers when <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> (select all) is pressed. Why is that?

I need to reliably trigger the `OnChange` event only when the text in the `TEdit` really changes. Unfortunately, no `OnBeforeChange` event is available so I can compare the text before and after a change.

So, how to implement a reliable `OnChange` event for `TEdit`?

Comment: Is this VCL or FMX?

Comment: Why does it matter if OnChange fires?  Perhaps there's a more elegant solution?

Comment: @J... - Perhaps, but the fact that OnChange triggers when there is no actual change is interesting enough :) Reason: In the OnChange even I create and assign an unique ID to the file entered by the user in the Edit box. If the event triggers more than once, more than one ID is generated and I don't want that. But as you said, I can change the design to go around that pesky OnChange.

Comment: @NAZCA by using OnChange, you would be generating a new ID every time the user types a new character. Why not require the user to click a button or menu item or something after input has been fully entered?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Yes, I will change the design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's not a bad base implementation:

```
procedure TCustomEdit.CNCommand(var Message: TWMCommand);
begin
  if (Message.NotifyCode = EN_CHANGE) and not FCreating then Change;
end;
```

This message comes not taking in consideration that the 'A' that is the button that is firing the EN_CHANGE, currently comes together with the state of ctrl pressed.

What you can do is check if Ctrl is pressed or not:

```
procedure TForm44.edt1Change(Sender: TObject);

  function IsCtrlPressed: Boolean;
  var
    State: TKeyboardState;
  begin
    GetKeyboardState(State);
    Result := ((State[VK_CONTROL] and 128) <> 0);
  end;
begin
  if IsCtrlPresed then
    Exit;

  Caption := 'Ctrl is not pressed';
end;
```

To avoid reading the state of the whole key board, you can do what was suggested by David Heffernan:

```
procedure TForm44.edt1Change(Sender: TObject);

  function IsCtrlPresed: Boolean;
  begin
    Result := GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0;
  end;
begin
  if IsCtrlPresed then
    Exit;

  Caption := 'Ctrl is not pressed';
end;
```

Comment: `GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL)<0` is the idiom here. Wasteful to read the entire keyboard state.

Comment: Its not a case that performance will be a problem, but I agree with David

Comment: No, perf isn't going to be an issue but you may as well be efficient when it's easy to do so and the code is simpler.

Comment: Totally agree David , I will attach your resolution when I get home

Comment: I wonder, are there are other events that will trigger an OnChange event without changing the text, other than using the Ctrl Key?